# How to perform url error for a form in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms, form-submit

I am trying to perform an url error for my form and it is validating, but the problem is, before I use validation while I'm submitting my form but when I changed to url validation, then the form is not showing an error when submitted with empty field.

```
<div class="col_full">
    <label for="newsUrl">Urlss <small>*</small></label>
    <input ng-class="{'error': submitted && addNews.newsUrl.$error.required}"  id="newsUrl" name="newsUrl" type="url" ng-model="news.url"  class="sm-form-control" required/>
</div>
```

Comment: I think your problem is simple but your explaination is not very clear.  It's better if you can paste full code instead of snippet like above so that someone can help you out with this issue. Thanks

Comment: grammar fixed

tag html5 removed

tags forms and form-submit added

Answer (score 0):

You have to validate url for that you need to check `addNews.newsUrl.$error.url` inside your `ng-class` and your code is something like this :

```
<div class="col_full">
             <label for="newsUrl">Urlss <small>*</small></label>
             <input ng-class="{'error': submitted && addNews.newsUrl.$error.required && addNews.newsUrl.$error.url}"  id="newsUrl" name="newsUrl" type="url" ng-model="news.url"  class="sm-form-control" required/>
 </div>
```

Hopefully this will help :)